# how to create on instance from ConsentForm

Tags: admob

I wanted it in Java and in Kotlin too if possible.

I try to use Google ConsentSDK to show in Android app consent form.

this is code

```
ConsentForm form = new ConsentForm.Builder(context, privacyUrl)
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    // Consent form loaded successfully.

                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                    // Consent form was displayed.

                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(
                        ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    // Consent form was closed.

                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    // Consent form error.

                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .build();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: to create a class that inherite from that one

Comment: Do you want to inherite that class or just show the form?

Comment: yes to inherit it

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @YubaSin Did you solve your problem?